# how to find the page position in pdf files using java or any other technology

Tags: java, pdf, annotations

I want to find the position of pdf files.I saw in google project .there is a pdf viewer called   apv-0.3.1dev13 android pdf viewer.here when i find the any text using find option.they are using JNI using c native code.i dont know how they find the text.can u tell me anybody to know the page postion of pdf files in any technology like  java or anyother.

Comment: Since the apv-project (http://code.google.com/p/apv/) is open-source and based on the mupdf-project (which is also open-source: http://www.mupdf.com/) you could browse the sources to find out for yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Remember if you convert between Java and PDF that PDF has origin bottom left while it is top left in Java.

Comment: i dont understand.plz clarify

Comment: If you use the PDF co-ordinates in Java2D you will need an AFF to flip the y co-ordinate (or subtract from height).

Comment: can u plz give some example or link

Comment: http://www.jpedal.org/PDFblog/2010/11/using-transforms-to-convert-pdf-co-ordinates-to-java-co-ordinates/

Comment: I want to add annotation in my android pdf viewer.some java grapics library are not supported by android.but i saw some pdf viewer in android.they are doing some annotation in java code itself.how are they doing?

Comment: Qoppa has an interesting Android viewer.